# jQuery validate input if element hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate a checkout form on an ecommerce site. The validation works great, however I only need to validate inputs that don't have the class `no-validate`

Can I use the `depends` method to do this check? For example, would something like this work:

```
checkoutForm.validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return element.not('.no-validate');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Or do I have to do something different to do this check? I thought about wrapping the entire `rules` array in a conditional like:

`if(!$(checkoutForm + ' input').hasClass('no-validate') { rules { //rules here } }`

but I would rather use the `depends` method if possible.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The validation works great, however I only need to validate inputs that don't have the class `no-validate`"*

Use the `ignore` option to ignore those…

```
checkoutForm.validate({
    ignore:  '.no-validate',
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Comment: Ah excellent! Thank you! I wasn't aware there was an `ignore` option. That will work perfectly. I will accept the answer as soon as I am able

Comment: @TyBailey, FWIW, every available option is outlined on that page I linked.